# Can't query EF context under TPL

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, task-parallel-library

I've got a process where I read thousands of records from a database, encode each into an individual XML message and send said message off to a WCF service.

The database is referenced via an EF4 model.  I'm using the TPL to parallelize the creation of the XML messages.  The problem occurs with the very first LINQ query:

```
var practice = (from patient in db.T_AccountHolder
                join practitioner in db.T_Practitioner on patient.DefaultPractitioner_ID equals practitioner.Practitioner_ID
                join _practice in db.T_Practice on practitioner.Practice_ID equals _practice.Practice_ID
                where patient.AccountHolder_ID == accountholder_id
                select _practice).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the following exception:

```
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
```

After lots of research I found out that EF doesn't assign a new key to similarly queried results, meaning that if you query the same table with the same result, the above exception will occur (because the result is in the same datacontext).

Since I'm using TPL, I'm in that exact situation.  Is my only recourse to NOT use EF?  Go back to normal ADO.NET queries?

I've searched up and down this excellent site and Google, but can't seem to find a similar type of question.

---

EDIT: Here is a stack trace of the error.

```
Exception message: An item with the same key has already been added.

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddStateManagerTypeMetadata(EntitySet entitySet, ObjectTypeMapping mapping)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.GetOrAddStateManagerTypeMetadata(Type entityType, EntitySet entitySet)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
at WCFServiceTest.Messages.CreateAccountHolderMessage(Int32 accountholder_id) in C:\Users\Chris\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WCFServiceTest\WCFServiceTest\Messages.cs:line 116
at WCFServiceTest.Messages.CreateParallelMessagesForAccountHolder(Int32 accountholder_id, manmayEntities _db, List`1 queue) in C:\Users\Chris\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WCFServiceTest\WCFServiceTest\Messages.cs:line 2482
at WCFServiceTest.ParallelWork.<>c__DisplayClass22.<ProcessData_EF>b__1f(Int32 patient_id) in C:\Users\Chris\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WCFServiceTest\WCFServiceTest\ParallelWork.cs:line 298
```

Comment: Specifying a new context with each thread isn't the answer.  Tried that this morning and get similar results ("entity already exists" type of errors).

Answer (score 1):

> After lots of research I found out that EF doesn't assign a new key to similarly queried results, meaning that if you query the same table with the same result, the above exception will occur (because the result is in the same datacontext).

That's not right. It's just fine to run that same query more than once. Try it in a test application.

If you select the same object into the context twice, by default the instances will be fixed up to be the same object. See the docs for `ObjectQuery.MergeOption`.

You *usually* see the error you give when you `AddObject()` twice with the same object.

I think your bug may be elsewhere.

BTW, I would write your query like this:

```
var practice = (from patient in db.T_AccountHolder
                where patient.AccountHolder_ID == accountholder_id
                select patient.Practitioner.Practice).FirstOrDefault();
```

Shouldn't make any difference to this issue, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, this is a test application I'm working through and multiple threads (via the TPL framework) do cause the stated exception.  Running the same code sequentially doesn't give the error.

Comment: I understand that, but I still don't think this line is causing the error. Have you looked at the stack trace associated with the exception? Can you post it?

Comment: The requested stack trace has been added.

Comment: Specifying a new context for each thread *is* required (as you say), but it isn't enough. You can't share (attached) entities at all between threads since that can implicitly bring in the other context. The stack trace shows that the ObjectStateManager appears to be shared by multiple threads, so that *may* be what is going on here.

Comment: Thanks, Craig.  I'm not sure how make these EF calls more explicit to avoid this error.  I've since re-written EF calls to normal ADO.net calls and I am getting expected results and benefits from using the TPL.

Answer (score 0):

I had Same issue, after reading carig answer the idea come that i can handle it using some lock...

it somehow working, i'm not sure how much , but last time i get an error after 3th or 4th time the multi threaded application, entered that part synchronously , but this time, it didn't for about 10 times (of test debugging) (BTW i  didn't face that error again),...

i have 2 thread that synchronously check the database for available jobs... then they look for the job at same time, due the lag that database has till it responds, so i think it does the job.

[image]

As you can see the thread are waiting at lock, so the EF each time process only one identical query, and it stop the bug...

better way will be that those thread reach for cached list, after some second you let the thread to trigger another thread which will fill the cache with new data, so you always have latest data, and you don't put database under pressure of fetching same data, so the lock can go away ... (if you don't need the exact lastest data)